# Different reading binary files in java / c++

Tags: java, c++, ifstream, datainputstream

My task is to read binary compressed files using JAVA.
there is a difference between reading as C++ and JAVA.

i don't know what the problem is when i read it with JAVA.
Please let me know the problem of JAVA code that i wrote.

please, help..

here is sample codes C++ and JAVA.
(no problem when reading with C++)

**# in C++**

```
ifstream file(path, ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);

while (!file.eof())
{
    file.read((char *)&j, sizeof(int));
    if (file.eof()) break;
    file.read((char *)&k, sizeof(int));
    file.read((char *)&result_c[j][k], sizeof(float));
    file.read((char *)&result_g[j][k], sizeof(float));

    for (int l = 0; l < 6; l++)
    {
        file.read((char *)&result_i[j][k][l], sizeof(float));
        file.read((char *)&result_t[j][k][l], sizeof(float));
    }
}
```

**# in Java**

```
        fin = new FileInputStream(new File(_path));
        bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
        din = new DataInputStream(bin);

        boolean _eof = false;
        while (!_eof) {

            int _ny = 0, _nx = 0;
            float _cResult = 0.0f, _gResult = 0.0f;
            float[] _iResult = new float[6];
            float[] _tResult = new float[6];

            try {

                _ny = din.readInt(); // ny
                _nx = din.readInt(); // nx
                _cResult = din.readFloat();
                _gResult = din.readFloat();

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    _iResult[i] = din.readFloat();
                    _tResult[i] = din.readFloat();
                }

            } catch (EOFException eofe) {
                _eof = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: C++ is not Java.  `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(float)` in C++ are not set in stone, unlike Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataInputStream` assumes the input is in network bye order. Your C++ code assumes it is in native byte order. If these are different, the results will be different too. `DataInputStream` also assumes that `int` and `float` are 32 bits, etc. See the Javadoc.